# Boostrap CSS accordion not collapsing on secondary pages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, business-catalyst

I'm using the Bootstrap Accordion Menu on my website and on the homepage it works perfectly but on any page except for the homepage, it simply doesn't work, when I click a menu collapse link, the URL simply changes to #collapseOne.

It may be of interest that I'm using this as a ContentHolder inside Business Catalyst. Here is the link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConduciveMammal/L2L77699/)

And [here's the website](http://radshaperc.businesscatalyst.com) where the problem occurs.

Many thanks.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"> RC Cars</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
            <li><h4 class="text-left"><a href="rc-electric-cars ">RC Electric Cars</a></h4></li>
            <li><h4 class="text-left"><a href="/">RC Petrol Cars</a></h4></li>
            <li><h4 class="text-left"><a href="/">RC Nitro Cars</a></h4></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"> RC Trucks</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
            <li><h4 class="text-left"><a href="rc-electric-cars ">RC Electric Trucks</a></h4></li>
            <li><h4 class="text-left"><a href="/">RC Petrol Trucks</a></h4></li>
            <li><h4 class="text-left"><a href="/">RC Nitro Trucks</a></h4></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"> RC Planes</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
            <li><h4 class="text-left"><a href="rc-electric-cars ">RC Electric Planes</a></h4></li>
            <li><h4 class="text-left"><a href="/">RC Petrol Planes</a></h4></li>
            <li><h4 class="text-left"><a href="/">RC Nitro Planes</a></h4></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you added javascript files right on the main page (and not added it in secondary pages).

You should move

```
<!-- jQuery Version 1.11.1 -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

to "header" tag content (just like .css files) and it will work on all pages.

Comment: Ahh! That was awfully dumb of me! Thanks very much. It now works properly! Thanks again

Comment: Hi, sorry to open this up again but it seems the problem is still occuring, only this time, it's three levels deep rather than two. So, domain.com works, domain.com/subdirectory works, but domain.com/subdirectory/nextsubdirectory doesn't work. Any ideas @kubik_rubic?

Comment: This happens because your links to local .js files not starts from "/". That means that you trying to get scripts from "http://radshaperc.businesscatalyst.com/rc-models/js/bootstrap.js" but not from "http://radshaperc.businesscatalyst.com/js/bootstrap.js". You should add "/" for all local paths. For scripts it will be <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script> and <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed your website.

Your code (other than homepage) is missing the link to JQuery js and Bootstrap JS

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script></p>
```

Add this to rest of the pages